# Optimize EF Insert for Parent and Children

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to figure out the best way to optimize inserting a parent that has many children.  I have some simple enough classes and the EF code is pretty straight forward.  Under normal circumstances things work fine.  However, when a lot of parents are being inserted at the same time along with these parents having a lot of children, it can cause deadlocks and timeouts for queries related to the parent table.  I'm assuming that each SaveChanges is starting a transaction and locking the parent table until all the inserts are complete.  Any advice for how to improve this process?  Below is a simplified version of the code, let me know if you need more.

```
var parent = new Parent();

foreach (var item in list)
{
    parent.Children.Add(item);
}

using (var context = new DBContext())
{
    context.Parents.Add(parent);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: How have you configured your tables/keys/indexes etc? Please try to give as much information as you can. There are situations where this won't be a performance problem. For example, if your keys are not `IDENTITY` you can add each entity to the context directly, including the children.

Comment: Yes, the tables related to these objects have primary keys and have been indexed on those keys as well as a few additional columns that are queried on.  The parent/children are also linked by foreign keys.

Comment: Are any of the primary keys `IDENTITY`?

Comment: Yes, both the keys for Parent and Child are IDENTITY.

Comment: I never had an issue in such a scenario, can you please provide the actual scenario?